# How can I get return a promise's value from an angular service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I am using $resource, but can just easily use $http (which ever can make this work for me)...

I'd like a service/factory called `User` and would like to interact with it like so:

```
var user = new User()

user.name() // 'Joe User'
```

But no matter how I try, I can only get a promise from my service object and have to use the `.then` method to resolve the promise.

Can't I resolve it from within the `User` service and just send the value from various method calls like `.name`, `.email`, etc?

If so, how?

**Here is my service object (using CoffeeScript)**

```
'use strict'

class User
  constructor: ($resource) ->
    @$resource = $resource '/api/v1/users/:id'

  current: ->
    @$resource.get(id: 'current').$promise

  name: ->
    # I'd like to call current() here and just get the data.name out of it.


angular.module('myApp').service 'User', ['$resource', User]
```

**Here I've modified the example to illustrate further what I'm confused about:**

```
'use strict'

class User
  constructor: ($resource) ->
    @$resource = $resource '/api/v1/users/:id'

  current: ->
    @user = @$resource.get(id: 'current')
    return @user


angular.module('myApp').service 'User', ['$resource', User]
```

If I call `User.current()` I get:

```
Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false, toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}
  > $promise: Promise
  > $resolved: true
  > user: Object
    > id: 1
    > first_name: "Joe"
    > last_name: "User"
  > __proto__: Resource
```

So in my mind, I should be able to call `User.current().user` but when I do, I get `undefined`

Comment: Please post your service code

Comment: You might be able to use the transformResponse option.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I'm using coffee script, but will edit my post to show it.

Comment: In general, you should not be newing your classes up. You should be using angular's dependancy injection. That aside, with your code you can get at your returned user object using the promise. Something like: var name; user.name.then(function(n) {name = n});

Comment: @Martin That's what I'm already doing.. but I wanted a more "ruby" way where just calling var user = User.find(1) would return a user.

Comment: @Nathan, the problem with that is Javascript is not ruby. You cannot write asynchronous code with a synchronous language like ruby. As such, it would be taking a big step backwards to write synchronous code with Javascript, though it is possible. It's just a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

> But no matter how I try, I can only get a promise from my service object and have to use the .then method to resolve the promise.

That's how promises work.

Since services in Angular are singletons, the good thing is that you don't have to repeat this action. The bad thing is that you have to do it once at some point.

Technically, you could do it on app init, run the fetching and store it into a service variable. Then you'll only need to read that variable from the controllers.

So, you're on a right track, just make sure you initialize that service when the app loads and before the user interaction starts.

---

If you're in for an out of the box solution, consider keeping such data in a localStorage or sessionStorage, depending on the purpose.

Comment: I suppose I can use a factory, from which I understand can be "newed" up. Either way, so long as I have an object that can make the server calls and respond to my specific method calls. Do you think you can provide an example of how to make that work?

Comment: Well, it's basic stuff really, it only depends on how you want to use it. Perhaps a module run block might be the easiest: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module